# "mongod" execution terminates immediately

Tags: mongodb

Error that i cant figure out as Im new to using mongoDB... it says that data/db not found and then it terminates..... Do I need to create this folder?

```
2016-01-27T18:14:41.788+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8556 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=andrews-hp
2016-01-27T18:14:41.796+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2016-01-27T18:14:41.800+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.1
2016-01-27T18:14:41.803+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2
2016-01-27T18:14:41.808+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-01-27T18:14:41.813+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-01-27T18:14:41.817+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-01-27T18:14:41.820+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-01-27T18:14:41.825+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2016-01-27T18:14:41.830+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-01-27T18:14:41.834+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-01-27T18:14:41.837+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-01-27T18:14:41.842+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2016-01-27T18:14:41.849+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: Dear friend please follow all the instructions properly. You have to define a place where all your files will be saved. You can do it wherever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you do, I have it under C:.

C:\data\db